# Squid cache, disable all caching

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

Squid 2.7 (installed on a Windows box) is causing problems having cached a "server down for maintenance) page for a web service used here. How do you totally disable caching in squid cache?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make and acl for that domain and disable cache for it:

```
acl nocache dst .domain.dom  
cache deny nocache
```

Check the syntax anyway.